# Spock blocks - Best Practices

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

Trying to implement some best pratices to the spock blocks in the project and was wondering if there is anything else to follow other than using action calls in when/and block and assertions in then.

Any documentation that I can look at?

Please help

Comment: Please note that your question is off-topic for SO. Quoting one reason for close votes (you already have received two such votes, BTW): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

Rob Fletcher who has written one of the books on Spock: "Up and Running"  (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920038597.do)  did a presentation a couple of years back: "Idiomatic Spock". It is a really great resource on best practices for Spock test. It is worth a watch: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvDoieRf4po